# Expressão regular

Tags: java, regex

Tenho uma dúvida de como posso fazer uma expressão regular para remover mascaras de telefone, cpf, cnpj.

Consegui fazer para tirar ("-") do CEP

```
String[] cepText = edtCep.getText().toString().split("-");
```

ai no caso de telefone tem `()#####-####` como posso fazer para remover?

Comment: Em resumo, você quer que fique somente os números?

Comment: Sim somente os números, @Randrade

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a expressão `[^0-9]` para obter somente os números.

Um exemplo seria esse:

```
    String tel = "(99) 9 9999-9999";
    String cpf = "111.111.111-11";
    String cnpj = "11.111.111/0001-11";

    System.out.println("Tel: " + tel.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
    System.out.println("CPF: " + cpf.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
    System.out.println("CNPJ: " + cnpj.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
```

[Veja funcionando no Ideone.](http://ideone.com/ik8Vub)

Answer (score 3):

Se sua intenção é deixar a string somente com os número utilize:

```
    String fone = "(51)9994-5845";
    String cpf = "025.454.644-55";
    String cnpj = "02.321.351/0001-35";

    System.out.println(fone.replaceAll("[^\\d ]", ""));
    System.out.println(cpf.replaceAll("[^\\d ]", ""));
    System.out.println(cnpj.replaceAll("[^\\d ]", ""));
```

Com a utilização da negação e valores diferentes de dígitos numéricos (^\d), serão removidos da string todos os caracteres diferentes de números. Isso evita a necessidade de ficar adicionando restrições a hífen, parenteses, pontos, etc...